# What is a signal in Django

Tags: python, django, signals

I come from a java background, but I'm working on a django-based website. To that end, every now and again I search for something, and I keep on seeing references to "signals". I'm unsure if this is a django thing, a python thing, or some sort of other thing that I never bothered about before.

Can anybody enlighten me what a "signal" is?

cheers.

UPDATE i have zero idea about signals. I know, I know, this is probably a *big* question... but you know how when you read about something, and you don't know what it is - that unknown unknown kinda thing? From the comments.... a signal is from the os?

Comment: Well... [http://google.com/search?q=python+signal](http://google.com/search?q=python+signal)'s top result is [the documentation for `signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html).

Comment: I think the question would be less ambiguous if you provided an exact quote that you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: ? so a signal is something that the os shoots off... and we catch that because, um?

Comment: @bharal: please provide a quote with an example.

Comment: @bharal please update question to relfect that you are talking about django signals and not OS signals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ouch, the comments are all ignoring the obvious answer Yes, there are OS signals, but in a Django app it would be far more likely to be referring to [Django's signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). They let you listen for certain events that happen in a Django application.

Comment: ah, so a (django) signal is different from whatever signals have been linked to in the comments section, riiiight?  Also, yep, I was enquiring about django signals